# Read ruleset topic/partition by multiple kafka stream instances of the same app

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I am having a Kafka Stream app that does some processing in a main event topic and I also have a side topic that
is used to apply a ruleset to the main event topic.

Till now the app was running as a single instance and when 
a rule was applied a static variable was set for the other processing operator (main topic consumer) to continue 
operating evaluating rules as expected. This was necessary since the rule stream would be written to a single partition depending 
on the rule key literal e.g. <"MODE", value> and therefore that way (through static variable) all the other tasks 
involved would made aware of the change.

Apparently though when deploying the application to multiple nodes this approach could not work since having a
single consumer group (from e.g. two instance apps) would lead only one instance app setting its static variable to 
the correct value and the other instance app never consuming that rule value (Also setting each instance app to a 
different group id would lead to the  unwanted side-effect of consuming the main topic twice)

On the other hand a solution of making the rule topic used as a global table would lead to have the main processing 
operator querying the global table every time an event is consumed by that operator in order to retrieve the latest rules.

Is it possible to use some sort of a global table listener when a value is introduced in that topic to execute some 
callback code and set a static variable ?

Is there a better/alternative approach to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a `GlobalKTable`, you can fall back to `addGlobalStore()` that allows you to execute custom code.